# How to construct efficient queries in C# LINQ to filter data

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a collection `List<Person> Members`. I need to filter the list based on some criteria.

Kindly refer the following C# code:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Person> Members = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { ID = 101, Name = "Harry", Department = "Testing", Gender = "Male", Role = "Manager"},
        new Person() { ID = 102, Name = "Peter", Department = "Development", Gender = "Male", Role = "Manager"},
        new Person() { ID = 103, Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development", Gender = "Female", Role = "Assistant"},
        new Person() { ID = 104, Name = "Raj", Department = "Development", Gender = "Male", Role = "Manager"},
        new Person() { ID = 105, Name = "Kaliya", Department = "Testing", Gender = "Male", Role = "Assistant"},
    };
}
```

The model class is:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Now consider the scenarios

**Scenario #1** : Search with ID

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> searchCriteria = new List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ID", "102")
    };
```

**Scenario #2** : Search with ID & Department

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> searchCriteria = new List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ID", "101"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DEP", "Testing")
    };
```

**Scenario #3** : Search with Department, Gender and Role

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> searchCriteria = new List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DEP", "Development"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Gender", "Male"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Role", "Manager"),
};
```

The searching query should be like

```
var iQuery = Members.AsQueryable();

foreach (var item in searchCriteria)
{
    switch (item.Key)
    {
        case "ID":
            iQuery = iQuery.Where(p => p.ID == int.Parse(item.Value));
            break;

        case "Name":
            iQuery = iQuery.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(item.Value));
            break;

        case "DEP":
            iQuery = iQuery.Where(p => p.Department == item.Value);
            break;

        case "Gender":
            iQuery = iQuery.Where(p => p.Gender == item.Value);
            break;

        case "Role":
            iQuery = iQuery.Where(p => p.Role == item.Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

In my real project I have more than 1000K records in the database. Instead of

```
var iQuery = Members.AsQueryable();
```

I'm using

```
var iQuery = db.Members.AsQueryable();
```

It takes more than 20 to 25 seconds to query the data. Kindly assist me how to construct more efficient queries in C# LINQ to filter the data.

Comment: Use .ToList => `var iQuery = db.Members.AsQueryable().ToList();` , so it caches instead of requeries.

Comment: Why are you calling .AsQueryable() on a list ? Its just not usefull, and has a negative impact on performance. Morevover,  i'm not sure what "Lakh" stands for, but if it's 10k records, that really nothing, it should take < 1ms (on an IEnumerable)

Comment: @Olivier he probably requeries automatically every loop when he calls the where clauses, it connects to sql server

Comment: @Olivier 10 Lakh means 1000K.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - You are a Genius, so, don't think all are Genius. Here I can't able to use that code. So, I'm seeking help. If you can, please provide your code. It will helpful for me.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Thanks. Can you please provide any suggestion for my question please...

Comment: How performance are for a simple hard-coded query iQuery = iQuery.Where(x => x.Gender == "Male")?

Comment: the main points where you are probably losing efficiency is on enumeration, everytime you convert the data to a solid type you run the query again, it's not shown in your code but i suspect you are calling ToList as you are also calling AsQueryable which would only be needed if you have changed the type back to list

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem if appropriate indexes are in place. You should analyze the query execution plan and see if it gives you any hints on adding indexes. There's *no way* to improve the performance by changing C# code.

Comment: @IRPunch Lakh is *not* a known software development term. I know that it is a common word in a specific language though.

Comment: @IRPunch instead of loading everything in memory and trying to query it, use an ORM like EF or L2S and let *it* do the querying. In-memory queries without indexing use a *lot* of CPU to scan *everything*. A simple query though would return the appropriate results much faster, use available indexes and wouldn't consume any CPU cycles worth mentioning

Comment: Add `if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.Database.Log = s => Debug.Write(s);
            }` inside you DbContext constructor. It will show you what queries are being ran.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't with what LINQ is actually doing. The query for scenario 2 would just create something *similar* to:

```
SELECT * FROM
PERSON
WHERE Department = N'Development'
AND Gender = N'Male'
AND Role = N'Manager'
```

You need to run this against the database directly to figure out what's your performance bottleneck. You're most likely missing indexes and therefore forcing your database server to scan the entire table to get the result set back.

If you're using SQL Server, try running a profiler to determine the exact query that (assuming) LINQ-to-EF is generating and tune that.

Answer (score -2):

You need to optimize your DB, take a look on index

You can also do the same request with [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

```
    public class NamedPersonSpecification : AbstractSpecification<Person>
{
    private string _name;
    public NamedPersonSpecification(string name)
    {
        this._name= name;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(Person o)
    {
        return o.Name.Equals(_name);
    }
}
```

And Query like this:

```
IQueryable<T>.Where(specification.IsSatisfiedBy)
```

The advantage is to be more clear to request your LINQ

Comment: With LINQ available, this should be considered an *anti*-pattern. In any case, this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Anti pattern of wich pattern ? Expose your IQueryable outiside of your repository, is pattern Leak, Specification pattern is just exactly proper(pattern) way to do what he want to do

Comment: You misunderstand what LINQ is/does. It's an *abstract* interface over any kind of collection. LINQ *is* agnostic regarding the actual *transaltion* - this is performed by the providers, not LINQ. On the consumer side it's not that different from what the Specification pattern would look, without the language support of course. On the provider side, the Specification pattern reimplements what any LINQ provider would also implement - without the infrastructure support.

Comment: You could say that the Specification pattern is just as leaky (or not) as LINQ. Given LINQ, Specification is an antipattern because it reimplements what is already available